# How do I put listener in web.xml java?

Tags: java, listener

I have created web application and I'd like to know where do I put my listener in the web.xml.

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProcessReg</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ProcessReg</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>pract123</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:odbc:practODBC</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>config</listener-class>
    </listener>         
  </servlet>
```

The error message I received is:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'listener'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":init-param, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":load-on-startup, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":run-as, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":security-role-ref}' is expected. [17]
```

Here's my config file:

```
public class config implements ServletContextListener {
private static final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "config";
private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    ServletContext servletContext = event.getServletContext();
    String databaseName = servletContext.getInitParameter("pract123");
    try {
           dataSource = (DataSource) new    InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp      /env/jdbc/TestDB");  
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Config failed: datasource not found", e);
    }}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    // NOOP.
}

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

public static config getInstance(ServletContext servletContext) {
    return (config) servletContext.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Use fully qualified name of the listner class.

Comment: Much easier to use annotation [`@WebListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/annotation/weblistener) instead of writing an XML file, in modern Jakarta EE. See [tutorial on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/servletcontextlistener-servlet-listener-example). See the [Jakarta Servlet spec](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are doing is you are mixing up the `<servlet>` and `<listener>` tags. They should be separate.

That should be

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProcessReg</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ProcessReg</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>pract123</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:odbc:practODBC</param-value>
    </init-param>       
  </servlet>

<listener>
        <listener-class>fully.qaulified.path.ContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

or

```xml
<listener>
          <listener-class>fully.qaulified.path.ContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProcessReg</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ProcessReg</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>pract123</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:odbc:practODBC</param-value>
    </init-param>       
  </servlet>
```

And in your class

```
package fully.qaulified.path;
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
..
..
```

**As a side note:**

In Java, class names start's with capital letters.  `public class config`  should be

```
public class Config
```

Comment: Shouldn't it go before the servlet definition as well?

Comment: @DaveHowes No need.Thing here is you should not mix up. :)

Comment: Thanks Suresh.  I didn't use package.  But now I have another error:Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class Config
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataSource.  How to overcome this error?

Comment: Karen I suspect you have a wrong import in your config file of Datasource file .edit your post with showing imports.

Comment: Doesn't allow me to edit.  So here's the imports.  import javax.activation.DataSource;
       import javax.naming.InitialContext;
       import javax.naming.NamingException;
       import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
       import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
       import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

Comment: Delete this import: `import javax.activation.DataSource`  and write , `import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource`

Comment: Thanks Suresh.  I deleted javax.activation.DataSource. Netbeans rejected org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource and suggested import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource; Now, the problem is resolved.  THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP :)

Answer (score 1):

Listener should not be within a `servlet` tag and provide fully qualified name

```xml
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.somePackage.ListenerClass</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 1):

Listener tag should be defined under web-app tag.

```xml
<web-app>
   <display-name>MyListeningApplication</display-name>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>config</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <servlet-name>ProcessReg</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>ProcessReg</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>pract123</param-name>
       <param-value>jdbc:odbc:practODBC</param-value>
   </init-param>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

as you see in the content model of wep-app:

```
Content Model : (((description*, display-name*, icon*)) | distributable | context-param | filter | filter-mapping | 
listener | servlet | servlet-mapping | session-config | mime-mapping | welcome-file-list | error-page | jsp-config | 
security-constraint | login-config | security-role | ((env-entry*, ejb-ref*, ejb-local-ref*, ((service-ref*)), resource-
ref*, resource-env-ref*, message-destination-ref*, persistence-context-ref*, persistence-unit-ref*, post-
construct*, pre-destroy*)) | message-destination | locale-encoding-mapping-list)*
```

it is a sibling of `servlet` not a child:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProcessReg</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ProcessReg</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>pract123</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:odbc:practODBC</param-value>
    </init-param>        
</servlet>

<listener>
    <listener-class>config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

web.xml would be

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.my.ServletContextClass</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>pract123</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:odbc:practODBC</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and com.my.ServletContextClass.java would be

```
public class ServletContextClass implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        String value = context.getInitParameter("pract123");
        System.out.println("value: " + value);
    }

}
```

enjoy coding :)